# Pigeonhole : subset coloring

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $X$ be the set that has $n$ elements.

Let $C$ be set of colors that has $p$ elements, where $p \geq 1$.

Find the largest $p$ satisfying the following properties,

if each subset of $X$ is colored with only one color, then there exist distinct subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ such that set $A, B, A \cup B, A \cap B$ are of the same color.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Let $X = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$

and $X_i = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_i\}$

Let $A = X_i$ and $B = X_j$ where $i>j$

$X_i \cap  X_j = X_j$

$X_i \cup  X_j = X_i$

Please suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we see that if $p=n$ then two sets among following $n+1$ sets:

$$\emptyset,\;\;\;\{1\},\;\;\;\{1,2\},\;\;\;\{1,2,3\},\;\;....\;\{1,2,3,...,n\}, $$

must be the same color and thus for $p=n$ we have desired coloring.

Now let us show that coloring with $n+1$ is not necessarily ok. For example:

Let's color with

color $C_0$: all sets with 0 elements

color $C_1$: all sets with 1 element

color $C_2$: all sets with 2 elements

.
.
.

color $C_n$: all sets with n elements

Clearly this coloring doesn't satisfy desired condition, so $p_{\max} =n$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your help :)